# GET_TIME in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a code that is supposed to give me the compilation time for the procedure, but it only gets me 0 secs! Is the calculation wrong? Is there any other way?

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE proc_time AS
    v NUMBER := 1;
    x NUMBER := 0;
    counter number := 0;
    summ NUMBER;
    ex_start NUMBER;
    ex_end NUMBER;
    ex_time NUMBER;
    BEGIN
    ex_start := dbms_utility.get_time;
    while  counter <= 19
    loop  
        counter := counter + 1;
        summ := x+v;    
        x := v;
        V := summ;  
        dbms_output.put_line('Fibonacci nr'||counter||': '||summ);
    END loop;
  ex_end := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME;
  ex_time := (ex_end-ex_start)/100; 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Exekveringstid: ' || ex_time || ' sekunder.' );
END;
/
```

Comment: Compilation time or execution time?

Comment: execution time! I noticed now I happend to write compliation when I ment execution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As explained in the above answer by Lalit. Your snippet runs too fast
>   to calculate the time difference. Try to increase the while loop with
>   some greater number and here you go !!!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_time
AS
  v        NUMBER := 1;
  x        NUMBER := 0;
  counter  NUMBER := 0;
  summ     NUMBER;
  ex_start NUMBER;
  ex_end   NUMBER;
  ex_time  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  ex_start := dbms_utility.get_time;
  dbms_output.put_line('start time ==>'||NVL(ex_start,0));
  WHILE counter <= 190000
  LOOP
    counter := counter + 1;
    summ    := x       +v;
    x       := v;
    V       := summ;
    --        dbms_output.put_line('Fibonacci nr'||counter||': '||summ);
  END LOOP;
  ex_end := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME;
  dbms_output.put_line('End time ==>'||ex_end);
  ex_time := (ex_end-ex_start);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Exekveringstid: ' || ex_time || ' sekunder.' );
END;

set serveroutput on;
exec proc_time;

-------------------------------OUTPUT----------------------------------------

start time ==>1761607275
End time ==>1761607281
Exekveringstid: 6 sekunder.
```

Comment: I suspected that it was too short :-P Thank you Lalit and Avrajit for yor help :-)

Answer (score 1):

- Perhaps, it is executing too quickly. You can try to increase the number of **loops** instead of `19` to something larger.
- Also, it would give you the **execution tim**e, not the **compilation time**. The procedure is already compiled and stored in database. The time in the output is at run time, i.e. when you execute the procedure.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_time
  2  AS
  3    l_start  NUMBER;
  4    l_loops  NUMBER := 10000000;
  5    l_number NUMBER := 0;
  6  BEGIN
  7    l_start := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
  8    FOR i IN 1 .. l_loops
  9    LOOP
 10      l_number := l_number + i;
 11    END LOOP;
 12    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('time taken: ' || (DBMS_UTILITY.get_time - l_start) || ' hsecs');
 13  END test_time;
 14  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> BEGIN
  2     test_time;
  3  END;
  4  /
time taken: 101 hsecs

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Unit `hsecs` seems to be very *proprietary*, better use SI conform prefix [Centi-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centi-) , i.e. `csec`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative use the `TIMESTAMP` data type, this supports up to nanoseconds (provided your server supports it as well)

```
DECLARE
    ex_start TIMESTAMP(9);  
    Duration INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND;

    v        NUMBER := 1;
    x        NUMBER := 0;
    counter  NUMBER := 0;
    summ     NUMBER;

BEGIN
    ex_start := LOCALTIMESTAMP;  
    WHILE counter <= 10000 LOOP
        counter := counter + 1;
        summ    := x       +v;
        x       := v;
        V       := summ;
    END LOOP;

    Duration :=  LOCALTIMESTAMP - ex_start;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( EXTRACT(SECOND FROM Duration) /1000||' msec.');
END;
```